# Wamp is not working after Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: apache, windows-10, wampserver

WampServer worked fine on my computer running Windows 8.1.  I've upgraded to Windows 10, and now Wamp is not working.  The WAMP icon is red.  I've looked into the Internet Information Services and found that World Wide Web Services folder was unchecked.   I went to services.msc and the World Wide Web Publishing Service is missing from the list. Took off skype from port80.  I've tried changing the port address in httpd.conf to 8090 and 9080.   I tested port80 through WAMP - Apache interface and found out that `"Your port 80 is not actually used".`   I'm not very good at using the command prompt.  I don't know how to ensure that Apache uses port 80.   I'm asking if this the problem and how to fix it.  Or at least how to get WAMP working again.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you had WAMPServer installed before you upgraded to Windows 10 then  the solution is simple. The problem is that the W10 upgrade does not know about the Apache and MYSQL (wampmysqld and wampapache) services, and therefore does not re-register them.

All you have to do is this using the wampmanager menus

```
wampmanager -> MYSQL -> Service -> Install Service
wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Install Service
```

Its probably a good idea to the exit WAMPServer and then restart it, but not usually necessary.

Comment: yes... I've installed a new version of windows and it's really necessary to install mysql & apache2 services again. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I tried several ways to make it run but it didn't. Suddenly, I selected a different version of PHP from WAMP tray and it did the trick. May be it will help many out there facing this issue.