# wampserver icon is always orange

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

I was using wamp for a year, but suddenly stopped working. I think the problem is Apache.

The icon is orange and doesn't turn to green. I have tried many ways, disabling IIS, quitting SKYPE, disabling World Wide Web publishing services etc... but still the icon is orange.Any help would be appreciated.

I am running Windows 10 64 bit and Wamp Server 2.5 .
 If I ask to Test Port 80, I get the following message

> Your port 80 is not actually used.
>
> Press Enter to exit...

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671456/wampserver-orange-icon/21678795#21678795 and then let us know if it is Apache or MySQL that is the reason why WAMPServer's icon is orange

Comment: Did you upgrade to Windows 10 after installing WAMPServer 2.5?

Comment: If you did upgrade to W10 after installing WAMPServer then this is a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34659887/wamp-is-not-working-after-windows-10-upgrade/34673095#34673095